# Copied version of RDL gives Name cannot begin with the '>' character, hexadecimal value 0x3E. Line 5645, position 64

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

**Scenario:** I created a SSRS Report in Visual Studio 15. The report works, I can preview it without errors. I made a copy of the RDL file by right clicking and copying and pasting it withing Visual Studio. When I attempt to preview the copy I get the following error:

> Name cannot begin with the '>' character, hexadecimal value 0x3E. Line
>   5645, position 64

What's even weirder is I deleted everything (DataSets, datasources, parameters etc) and I still get the same error. What's really strange is it still refers to line 5645. After deleting everything from the report there are only 29 lines!

Another thing I found odd, and this could be key to solving the mystery is the file name and line # is blank in the error window.

[image]

Below is the the content of the RDL file after deleting it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <Height>13.03466in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>33.9775in</Width>
      <Page>
        <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>9922849d-3925-4879-911b-cdeeeb45c5d6</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was changing the project from Release to Debug mode:

[image]